# [] operator not supported for strings

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

For this code i get the error.at this line   `$sname[] = $rs['StudentId'];`
PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings
    $sname = array();
    $i=0;

```
foreach($data as $rs){

    foreach($SchoolName as $sname){
//      echo $rs['SchoolName'].'=='.$sname."<br />";
        echo $i."<br />";                  
        if($rs['SchoolName'] == $sname){
            $sname[] = $rs['StudentId'];
        }   
        $i++;  
    }                   
}
```

Comment: [] operator not supported for strings...please how to solve this

Comment: I assume $rs is a string and not an array. Check the data of $rs with var_dump for example.

Comment: Err. Don't try to treat strings as if they are arrays…

Comment: I dont know, what you want to achieve. `$data`, `$rs` and so on are not very clear names for variables. describe what they are.

Comment: Also `$sname = $rs['StudentId'];` in `if` statement won't work... You'll have to do it this way: `$SchoolName[$i] = $rs['StudentId'];`...

Comment: KingCrunch@ i just want to store string in the array...

Comment: I wan t this array...... Store student id with school name       
Array
( 
  [Southwestern College] => 10002,2003,20225
  [National University] => 10282,90281
  [Western Governors University] => 156
)

Comment: Could you show us a print_r($rs).

Comment: This is the var_dump of `$rs` or `$data`???

Comment: var_dump :  array(17) {
    
  ["SchoolName"]=>
  string(3) "Roy"
  
}

Comment: $SchoolName array :
Array
(
    [0] => 10003
    [1] => Southwestern College
    [2] => National University
    [3] => Western Governors University
    [4] => Southwestern College Admissions Center - Evaluations Dept
 
)

Comment: $data array :
    [0] => Array
        (
            [STU_MANG_fname] => Jennifer
            [STU_MANG_lname] => patel
            [SchoolName] => Southwestern College Admissions Center - Evaluations Dept
            [ShipAddress1] => 900 Otay Lakes Road            
            [ShipState] => CALIFORNIA
        )

Comment: Please, edit Your question and provide us with FULL `var_dump($data)` and `var_dump($schoolName)`. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/Z1zmlr0U)

```
$SchoolNames = Array(10003, "Southwestern College", "National University", "Western Governors University", "Southwestern College Admissions Center - Evaluations Dept");
$data = array(
    0 =>  Array(
        'STU_MANG_fname' => "Jennifer",
        'STU_MANG_lname' => "patel",
        'SchoolName' => "Southwestern College Admissions Center - Evaluations Dept",
        'ShipAddress1' => "900 Otay Lakes Road",
        'ShipState' => "CALIFORNIA" 
    )
);


foreach($data as $studen_info){
    foreach($SchoolNames as $id=>$school_name){
        if($studen_info['SchoolName'] == $school_name){
            $student_names[$school_name] = $id;
            //$student_names[$school_name] = $student_info['StudentId'];;
        }
    }
}

print_r($student_names);
```

there was no 'StudentId' in the student info array you gave me so I assume you want to use the key of the student array if there is in fact a 'StudentId'  use line i commented out

Comment: $rs is a array ,$rs['SchoolName'] => "school name"

Comment: What I'm saying is trying to aceess an array item on a string

Comment: I wan t this array...... Store student id with school name       
Array
( 
  [Southwestern College] => 10002,2003,20225
  [National University] => 10282,90281
  [Western Governors University] => 156
)

Comment: pleas put a dump of the full array in your post

Comment: $data array :
    [0] => Array
        (
            [STU_MANG_fname] => Jennifer
            [STU_MANG_lname] => patel
            [SchoolName] => Southwestern College Admissions Center - Evaluations Dept
            [ShipAddress1] => 900 Otay Lakes Road            
            [ShipState] => CALIFORNIA
        )

Comment: $SchoolName array :
Array
(
    [0] => 10003
    [1] => Southwestern College
    [2] => National University
    [3] => Western Governors University
    [4] => Southwestern College Admissions Center - Evaluations Dept
 
)

Comment: I wan t this array...... Store student id with school name Array ( [Southwestern College] => 10002,2003,20225 [National University] => 10282,90281 [Western Governors University] => 156 )

Comment: Is $data always a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Where to take student IDs from??? It is not in $rs nor in $schoolName...

Comment: David Grant @ yes,as shown in  array

Comment: shaddy@ : i remove that from array

Comment: So how can You build the desired array when You have removed 'StudenId' index from $rs array???

Comment: should i use intval() ????????/

Comment: $sname = array();
   $k=0;
   for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
   {
    for($j=0;$j<count($SchoolName);$j++)
    {
     if($data[$i]['SchoolName'] == $SchoolName[$j]){
      $sname[$SchoolName[$j]][] = intval($data[$i]['StudentId']);
     } 
    }    
   }

Comment: if (xmlhttp == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }

Here Correct Code 

 if (`xmlhttp.readyState` == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }

Comment: @allov I dont understand your comment are you asking a new question  ?

Answer (score 4):

In the following loop,

```
foreach ($SchoolName as $sname) {
```

You are assigning each element of `$SchoolName` to `$sname`.  Then on this line:

```
$sname[] = $rs['StudentId'];
```

You attempt to treat `$sname` as an array.  I suspect you have a duplicate variable name.

Comment: i declared : $sname = array();

Comment: and then you overwrite it in the inner loop. ;)

Comment: I wan t this array...... Store student id with school name Array ( [Southwestern College] => 10002,2003,20225 [National University] => 10282,90281 [Western Governors University] => 156 )

Comment: should i use intval() ????????/

Comment: https://ngl.usuniversity.edu/logs/phperrors.php

Comment: [05-May-2011 04:33:24] PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings in C:\NGL\NGL_Uresh\NewChangesFiles\transcriptRequest.php on line 1334

Comment: $sname = array();
   $k=0;
   for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
   {
    for($j=0;$j<count($SchoolName);$j++)
    {
     if($data[$i]['SchoolName'] == $SchoolName[$j]){
      $sname[$SchoolName[$j]][] = intval($data[$i]['StudentId']);
     } 
    }    
   }

Answer (score 0):

This should work - but You have to have `StudentId` index present in $rs array, too...

```
$data = array(
    array("SchoolName" => "Roy", "StudentId" => "1000,1001,1002"),
    array("SchoolName" => "MIT", "StudentId" => "2000,2001,2002"),
    array("SchoolName" => "Southwestern College", "StudentId" => "3000,3001,3002"),
    array("SchoolName" => "National University", "StudentId" => "4000,4001,4002"),
    array("SchoolName" => "Western Governors University", "StudentId" => "5000,5001,5002"),
);

$return = array();

foreach($data as $rs){
    $return[$rs['SchoolName']] = $rs['StudentId'];
}

print_r($return);
```

Live demo: http://codepad.org/HesEO4uF

Comment: $sname = array();
   $k=0;
   for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
   {
    for($j=0;$j<count($SchoolName);$j++)
    {
     if($data[$i]['SchoolName'] == $SchoolName[$j]){
      $sname[$SchoolName[$j]][] = intval($data[$i]['StudentId']);
     } 
    }    
   }

Comment: i don't undersantd where you go that array from ?

Comment: ok just that the op post many different arrays and I hadn't seen that one, just not how he had it setup

Comment: It is all totally weird and messed up and I regret I did even post here :-D So I proposed how it should look like and what he should do with it to achieve the desired result array...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sname = array();
            $k=0;
            for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            {   
                $id_str ='';            
                for($j=0;$j<count($SchoolName);$j++)
                {                   
                    if($data[$i]['SchoolName'] == $SchoolName[$j]){
                        $id_str .= intval($data[$i]['StudentId']).",";
                    }
                    $sname[$SchoolName[$j]] = $id_str;
                }               
            }
```